# Call method diagram error (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am encountering is that I just want to access the `alert` command inside window onload. The purpose of this code is that I want to wrap 5 different diagrams in methods like (table1(), table2(), table3(), table4(), table5()), then I wish to use JQuery event to enable the user too select which diagram they want to see once a time.

Below is a JavaScript file, keep in mind that the `alert` command is not accessible..

```
(function table4(){          

$(window).on("load", function() {
      alert('Test');
  });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load(function(){})` is only called if it's bound before the event.
Try to use the $(document).ready function:

```
(function table4(){          

$(document).ready(function() {
      alert('Test');
  });

}())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5jy7pu1/

Comment: This works, but how can I prevent all the diagrams running in the background by using JQuery? Because this decreases the performance..

Answer (score 0):

Dont "hide" in table4 function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert('Test');
}
```